# CRUD with generic classes (dao,service)

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, jpa, controller

I begin i big application with spring, hibernate,maven,jpa,springMVC.
For the moment i have 30 classes. (with interface for each class we have 60 classes)
I have two packages. (Dao and service)
For dao i use genericDao class.
My classe abstract for All Dao is :

```
>
package org.me.dao.jpageneric;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
 
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 
public abstract class GenericDAO<T, K> {
 
        @PersistenceContext(unitName="database")
        protected EntityManager em;
 
        protected Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(getClass());
 
        public abstract Query getByIdQuery(K id);
        public abstract Query getAllQuery();
 
        public T save(T saved) {
                if (saved == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("L'argument de save() ne doit pas être nul.");
                }

                return (T) em.merge(saved);
        } // save()
 
        public void delete(T deleted) {
                if (deleted == null) {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("L'argument de delete() ne doit pas être nul.");
                }
                em.remove(deleted);
        } // delete().
 
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T get(K id) {
                if (id == null) {
                   throw new IllegalArgumentException("L'argument de get() ne doit pas être nul.");
                }
                Query query = getByIdQuery(id);
                return (T) query.getSingleResult();
        } 
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<T> getAll() {
                logger.debug("Récupération de tous les objets");
                Query query = getAllQuery();
                return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
        }
```

Every Dao must extends this classe and implemente his interface( and i have to make this for 30 others classes). I hope it's a good practice.

After, i have another abstract generic class for services classes.

```
package org.me.service.generic;
 
import java.util.List;
 
public abstract class GenericService<T,K> {
 
        public abstract T create(T saved);
        public abstract void remove(T deleted);
        public abstract T findById(K id) ;
        public abstract List<T> findAll();
 
}
```

Her the same things, all service classe must extend this generic service class and implement interface of each classe.
Is the good practice again ?

Of corse i have an interface for each classes (packages dao and service).

Another question : i have to create controllers, how i do ? To create a controller for each classes(is to say 30 controllers ?)
and how to do with pages html and jsp ?
Thank you.
And sorry my english is bad.:-)

Comment: Services and controllers should implement use-cases of your application. They should not contain arbitrary create, remove and find methods. Let's say you're implementing a Bank application. You really don't want to list all the accounts (which could be millions) or all the customers, right? Also, JPA has `EntityManager.find()` to get an entity by ID. Use that rather than a query.

Comment: thnks for those informations. i have changed what you say! more easy and very usefull. my application is for ambassy,travelling agency and foreign ministry.

Answer (score 2):

Spring-data-jpa replaces your GenericDAO.

You could look at [spring-data-rest](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest) for your crud services.

Alternatively, I recommend looking at spring-roo which scaffolds web UI's for crud operations.

Comment: thanks. yes there are a lot of that i didn't understand with spring-data-jpa! finally it's very easy to use. another question?it's possible to add spring-data-rest to spring-data-jpa?i saw spring-roo it's very interesting but i'm affraid with all frameworks.possible to work with spring-data-jpa,spring-data-rest and roo?

Comment: spring-data-rest builds upon spring-data-jpa, so once you have spring-data-jpa in place, then you can work on spring-data-rest.  spring-data-rest and spring-roo would not work nicely together I think.

Comment: just for informations. if i integrate spring-data-rest with spring-data-rest what about controller?it's embedded in or i have to create it?

Comment: looks like spring-data-rest provides a controller which maps directly to the jpa repo's, so you don't write controller or service layer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some of well regarded good practice in software programming are:

- DRY (Donot Repeat Yourself). If you find yourself copying the same code many times it's just a bug waiting to happen -- especially when time comes to refactor (change) that repeated code.
- Don't reinvent the wheel. Have a look at Spring Data JPA project, there's already [a generic DAO feature](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) you can use

As of Spring MVC controllers, I don't see why you need to superclass all your controller. You just need to annotate each controller class with `@Controller`. It is a good idea to encapsulate business functionality executed by controllers in a Service classes so you can reuse it in other places

Comment: as you know:my application count 30 entities. i already try spring Data JPA but i have to write each method implemented for all DAO(30 classes). with my solutions i don't have to do that. only make for example : public class AddressDAO extend GenericDao<Address, Integer> implements IAddress{ and i dont have to write any method in AddressDAO. but with JpaRepository i have to write all method and for all classes. i hope it's right my conception. if you see mistakes dont hesitate. thanks to controllers : i should create 30 controllers classes? or only one controllers for all classes? thakns

Comment: I will try spring-data-jpa

Comment: Just to mention it: you can also use generics on the controller level. One simple controller for CRUD operations for master data which gets the class name and id from a pathvariable or requestparameter is easily achievable.